# WordPress international targeting

Tags: wordpress, subdirectory

I have setup subdirectory for my  WordPress site like : [www.domain.com/sa](http://www.domain.com/sa) which is in the language Arabic, my question is if i want to say to google this subdirectory targeting saudi Arabia country what can i do
Note: i know that translate plugins make that but I don't want to translate it, i need it in the language of the main domain put target saudi
Thank you

I have setup subdirectory for my  WordPress site like : [www.domain.com/sa](http://www.domain.com/sa) which is in the language Arabic, my question is if i want to say to google this subdirectory targeting saudi Arabia country what can i do

Comment: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2012/05/multilingual-and-multinational-site